# Como instalar el paquete PyQt de Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

Me podrian ayudar a instalar el paquete PyQt de python junto con el PyQt Designer, para generar un entorno de desarrollo en Windows 10. Tambien me gustaria saber donde puedo encontrar los comandos que instalan estos paquetes.

Gracias.

Adjunto Imagenes donde salen los errores al instalar los paquetes.

[image: Instalacion de PYQT4 en Windows 10 para Python 2.7.16]

[image: Fallo de instalacion sip para PYQT4]

Comment: Unas consultas : ¿Visitaste la página oficial de PyQt? te arrojó algún error al tratar de instalarlo en Windows? Cuéntanos un poco más de tu problema para ver cómo ayudarte.

Comment: Estoy usando la version 2.7.16 de python para luego descargar el PyQt4_gpl_win-4.12.3 y el sip-4.19.16 para instalarlos por medio de cmd pero cuando ingreso los comandos y espero su instalacion inmediatamente me hala un error.

Comment: Bueno te arroja un error de compatibilidad, lo que pasa es que la versión 2.7 de Python está a punto de morir, si te fijas en  la documentación de PyQt4 toda la configuración la hacen en Python 3.4 si pudieras cambiarte a python 3.4 podrías utilizar PyQt5 sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

La Solucion es actualizar el python para el uso de pyqt4 o pyqt5, python no dara soporte a Python 2.7, es necesario actualizar.

Gracias.